# Apple rejected the app saying app uses a background mode

Tags: ios, app-store

The app which I submitted does not have any background location mode. I am not having "Required background modes" field in my plist. 
I even checked the device capabilities, Background modes is off.

From Apple as follows,

```
we found that your app uses a background mode but does not include the following battery use disclaimer in your Application Description:

"Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life."
```

Can any one please help me how to find out whether my app is using background location mode or not ?

Comment: hey had check bacckground mode in xcode first uncheck if you are using non backgroung for app

Comment: if you are using  xcode 5 then go to project capablaties  and then check you had on any of swith in it

Comment: Yes I already checked the capabilities and background modes switch is off.

Comment: http://support.ibuildapp.com/entries/21378561-App-Rejected-App-uses-a-background-mode-but-does-not-include-functionality-that-requires-that-mode-   may this url help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link will tell you about [Background fetch](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-background-fetch/).

If you really need the app to constantly monitor the location of the user's device then you should put the disclaimer in your app's description.

Comment: But my app does not monitors the location, it is not location based app.

Comment: This [link](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/App-rejection-reason-216-121874.S.139332634) may help you

Answer (score 1):

Remove CoreLocation Library from your libraries/frameworks folder and resubmit.